# How to use authenticate SharePoint O365 from a custom web api

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint-online

I need to build a custom Web API for which I need to connect to SharePoint and get the details.

How can I form the current context or what is the best way to implement that? I spent almost 3 days to understand the approach but it seemed too confusing, ay right point would be very helpful.

The API I am building will be used by some third-party tool to perform READ/WRITE operations.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on SharePoint version.
For online use [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/) To authenticate via graph you should use OAuth tokens.

For SharePoint on-premise use [CSOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code) To authenticate in CSOM you need to pass login name and password in code.

```
  ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteURL);
  ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(config.Login, config.Password);
```